# Tokenize Text and Analyze with Dictionary in Quanteda

Tags: r, quanteda

I am trying to do a text analysis using the `quanteda` packages in R and have been successful in gaining the desired output without doing anything to my texts. However, I am interested in removing stopwords and other common phrases to rerun the analysis (from what I am learning in other sources -- this process is called "Tokenizing"(?)). (The instructions are from https://data.library.virginia.edu/a-beginners-guide-to-text-analysis-with-quanteda/)

With the processed text, which I was able to do using the instructions and the `quanteda` package. However, I am interested in applying a dictionary for analyzing the text. How can I do that? Since it is hard to attach all my documents here, any hints or examples that I can apply would be helpful and greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Asking about tutorials or examples are off topic. But have a look at the [quanteda](https://quanteda.io/index.html) home page and specifically look at the example sections.

Comment: Thank you for this link. However, I posed the question because I already did that. I am not asking for a tutorial, per se, but helpful hints that can get me where I would like to be. Prior to my post, I looked over the internet for relevant clues and projects people have completed, but nothing has been very helpful.

Comment: https://tutorials.quanteda.io/basic-operations/dfm/dfm_lookup/

Comment: Thank you! And I apologize if this is a bit dumb, but for the output, are those values percentages or number of appearances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have used this library with great success and then merged by word to get the score or sentiment. Merge by word

```
library(tidytext)

get_sentiments("afinn")
get_sentiments("bing")
```

you can save it as a table

```
table <- get_sentiments("afinn")

total <- merge(data frameA,data frameB,by="ID")
```